# Get date difference in years (floating point)

Tags: r, date

I want to correct source activity based on the difference between reference and measurement date and source half life (measured in years). Say I have

```
ref_date <- as.Date('06/01/08',format='%d/%m/%y')
```

and a column in my `data.frame` with the same date format, e.g.,

```
today <- as.Date(Sys.Date(), format='%d/%m/%y')
```

I can find the number of years between these dates using the `lubridate` package

```
year(today)-year(ref_date)
[1] 5
```

Is there a function I can use to get a floating point answer `today - ref_date` = 5.2y, for example?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Yes, of course, use `difftime()` with an as numeric:

```
R> as.numeric(difftime(as.Date("2003-04-05"), as.Date("2001-01-01"), 
+                      unit="weeks"))/52.25
[1] 2.2529
R>
```

Note that we do have to switch to weeks scaled by 52.25 as there is a bit of ambiguity
there in terms of counting years---a February 29 comes around every 4 years but not every 100th etc.

So you have to define that. `difftime()` handles all time units up to weeks.  Months cannot be done for the same reason of the non-constant 'numerator'.

Comment: Thanks. I assume I can divide by 365.25 and omit `unit=weeks"

Comment: No, you need to -- just play with it to see. The unit auto-adjusts, try it with deltas of less than one, or even `POSIXct` objects (eg from `Sys.time()`).

Comment: And the weeks are always the same number in an year?

Comment: 52.25*7=365.75, is this OK? Wiki says that the gregorian calender has 365.2425 days... 365.2425/7=52.1775, How to do it right?

Answer (score 53):

The **lubridate** package contains a built-in function, **time_length**, which can help perform this task.

```
time_length(difftime(as.Date("2003-04-05"), as.Date("2001-01-01")), "years")
[1] 2.257534

time_length(difftime(as.Date("2017-03-01"), as.Date("2012-03-01")),"years")
[1] 5.00274
```

Documentation for the **lubridate** package can be found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/lubridate.pdf).

Comment: Do note @RenMa's answer below, as using difftime() can indeed give incorrect results. I happened to notice this when looking at the difference between 1948-12-07 and today (2018-11-29), which is 70.02466 via difftime() and 69.97808 via interval().
start <- as.Date("1948-12-07"); end <- as.Date("2018-11-29"); difftime(end, start) %>% time_length(unit = "years"); interval(start, end) %>% time_length(unit = "years")

Answer (score 24):

Inspired by [Bryan F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5203760/bryan-f), `time_length()` would work better if using interval object

```
time_length(interval(as.Date("2003-04-05"), as.Date("2001-01-01")), "years")
[1] -2.257534
time_length(difftime(as.Date("2017-03-01"), as.Date("2012-03-01")),"years")
[1] 5.00274
time_length(interval(as.Date("2017-03-01"), as.Date("2012-03-01")),"years")
[1] -5
```

You can see if you use `interval()` to get the time difference and then pass it to `time_length()`, `time_length()` would take into account the fact that not all months and years have the same number of days, e.g., the leap year.

Comment: Why do we get a negative sign after the time length calculation?

Comment: `interval(start_date, end_date)` basically uses end_date minus start_date. So if your start_date occurs after the end_date, the interval will be negative.

Answer (score 6):

Not an exact answer to your question, but the answer from [Dirk Eddelbuettel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel) in some situations can produce small errors.

Please, consider the following example:

```
as.numeric(difftime(as.Date("2012-03-01"), as.Date("2017-03-01"), unit="weeks"))/52.25
[1] -4.992481
```

The correct answer here should be at least 5 years.

The following function (using **lubridate** package) will calculate a number of full years between two dates:

```
# Function to calculate an exact full number of years between two dates
year.diff <- function(firstDate, secondDate) {
  yearsdiff <- year(secondDate) - year(firstDate)
  monthsdiff <- month(secondDate) - month(firstDate)
  daysdiff <- day(secondDate) - day(firstDate)

  if ((monthsdiff < 0) | (monthsdiff == 0 & daysdiff < 0)) {
    yearsdiff <- yearsdiff - 1
  }

  yearsdiff
}
```

You can modify it to calculate a fractional part depending on how you define the number of days in the last (not finished) year.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `AnnivDates()` of the package **BondValuation**:

```
R> library('BondValuation')
R> DateIndexes <- unlist(
+   suppressWarnings(
+     AnnivDates("2001-01-01", "2003-04-05", CpY=1)$DateVectors[2]
+     )
+   )
R> names(DateIndexes) <- NULL
R> DateIndexes[length(DateIndexes)] - DateIndexes[1]
[1] 2.257534
```

Click [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BondValuation/BondValuation.pdf) for documentation of the package **BondValuation**.

Answer (score 1):

To get the *date difference in years (floating point)* you can convert the dates to decimal numbers of Year and calculate then their difference.

```
#Example Dates
x <- as.Date(c("2001-01-01", "2003-04-05"))

#Convert Date to decimal year:
date2DYear <- function(x) {
  as.numeric(format(x,"%Y")) + #Get Year an add
    (as.numeric(format(x,"%j")) - 0.5) / #Day of the year divided by
    as.numeric(format(as.Date(paste0(format(x,"%Y"), "-12-31")),"%j")) #days of the year
}
diff(date2DYear(x)) #Get the difference in years
#[1] 2.257534
```

I subtract `0.5` from the day of the year as it is not known if you are at the beginning or the end of the day and `%j` starts with `1`.

I think the difference between `2012-03-01` and `2017-03-01` need *not* to be 5 Years, as 2012 has 366 days and 2017 365 and `2012-03-01` is on the 61 day of the year and `2017-03-01` on the 60.

```
x <- as.Date(c("2012-03-01", "2017-03-01"))
diff(date2DYear(x))
#[1] 4.997713
```

Note that using `time_length` and `interval` from `lubridate` need not come to the same result when you make a cumulative time difference.

```
library(lubridate)

x <- as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2012-03-01", "2012-12-31"))
time_length(interval(x[1], x[3]), "years")
#[1] 0.9972678
time_length(interval(x[1], x[2]), "years") +
 time_length(interval(x[2], x[3]), "years")
#[1] 0.9995509 #!
diff(date2DYear(x[c(1,3)]))
#[1] 0.9972678
diff(date2DYear(x[c(1,2)])) + diff(date2DYear(x[c(2,3)]))
#[1] 0.9972678

x <- as.Date(c("2013-01-01", "2013-03-01", "2013-12-31"))
time_length(interval(x[1], x[3]), "years")
#[1] 0.9972603
time_length(interval(x[1], x[2]), "years") +
 time_length(interval(x[2], x[3]), "years")
#[1] 0.9972603
diff(date2DYear(x[c(1,3)]))
#[1] 0.9972603
diff(date2DYear(x[c(1,2)])) + diff(date2DYear(x[c(2,3)]))
#[1] 0.9972603
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that only uses R base, although it only works with scalar values:

```
year.difference <- function (x, y) {
    x <- as.Date(x)
    y <- as.Date(y)
    if (x == y) {
        0
    } else if (x > y) {
        -year.difference(y, x)
    } else {
        k <- length(seq(x, y - 1, by = "years"))
        z <- seq(x, length.out = k + 1, by = "years")[c(k, k + 1)]
        k - 1 + (as.numeric(y - z[1]) / as.numeric(z[2] - z[1]))
    }
}
```

It correctly accounts for the extra days in leap years:

```
> year.difference("2024-02-01", "2024-02-02")
[1] 0.00273224
> year.difference("2025-02-01", "2025-02-02")
[1] 0.002739726
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are already using lubridate package, you can obtain number of years in floating point using a simple trick:

find number of seconds in one year:

```
seconds_in_a_year <- as.integer((seconds(ymd("2010-01-01")) - seconds(ymd("2009-01-01"))))
```

now obtain number of seconds between the 2 dates you desire

```
seconds_between_dates <- as.integer(seconds(date1) - seconds(date2))
```

your final answer for number of years in floating points will be

```
years_between_dates <- seconds_between_dates / seconds_in_a_year
```