# Is there a way to convert time difference in terms of years and months

Tags: r

Is there a way to convert below time difference in terms of years and months?

```
as.Date(Sys.Date()) - as.Date("2015-08-20")
Time difference of 2753 days
```

Expected output (Since it app.. around 7 years and 5 months?

```
7.5
```

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/a/15569373/13513328

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get date difference in years (floating point)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569333/get-date-difference-in-years-floating-point)

Comment: Did you mean years and fraction of a year as there is about 7.5 years between those dates but there is not 7 years and 5 months?

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below code

```r
library(lubridate)

months <- time_length(as.numeric(difftime(as.Date(Sys.Date()) , as.Date("2015-08-20"), units = 'days')), 'month')

years <- time_length(as.numeric(difftime(as.Date(Sys.Date()) , as.Date("2015-08-20"), units = 'days')), 'year')
```

Answer (score 0):

A trick using only base R is to add the `difftime` on to the first of January in the year 0 AD (this exists in R even if it didn't technically exist in reality).

The resulting date is the number of years, months and days of the difftime (with an extra day, which is easy to subtract)

```r
(as.POSIXct('0000-01-01') + (as.Date(Sys.Date()) - as.Date("2015-08-20"))) |>
  as.character() |>
  strsplit('-') |>
  getElement(1) |>
  as.numeric() |>
  setNames(c('years', 'months', 'days')) - c(0, 0, 1)
#>  years months   days 
#>      7      7     15
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate method using timeplyr.

```r
start <- as.Date("2015-08-20")
end <- as.Date("2023-03-04")

library(timeplyr)

time_diff(start, end, "months")
#> [1] 90.42857
time_diff(start, end, "years")
#> [1] 7.536986
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>